# Starting links with slash disables active class

Tags: html, jquery

My active class stopped working after I added a slash before my href links **(href="/link")**, it works if I remove it **(href="link")**, can anyone suggest a solution?

My working script without slash:

```
$(function() {
            $('nav a[href^="' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
        });
```

My blade file

```
<nav class="mt-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu"
                        data-accordion="false">
                        <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
                        with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="/home" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Dashboard
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="/investment" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Investments
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="/investor" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Investors
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="/product" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="nav-icon fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Products
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as it is (without using split("")[1]), see below working example.
There should be some other console error, please verify.

```js
$(function() {
var pathname = "/link";
$('nav a[href^="' + pathname + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
   color: green;
}
body {
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="/link"> link </a><br>
  <a href="/links"> links </a><br>
  <a href="/url"> url </a><br>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you reproduce your issue with code snippet or jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it

Comment: I tried this but now my active class appears on click and disappears on page load: `$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".nav-link").click(function() {
                $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });
        });`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here [Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/highlight-all-links-to-current-page/)

```
$(function(){
            $("a").each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                    }
            });
        });
```